# ¿Cómo llenar TreeView mediante txt en tiempo de ejecucion?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

bueno como verán necesito llenar un TreeView con un archivo de texto en tiempo de ejecución y nose de que manera hacerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradecería su ayuda! Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```
    // Limpia los nodos existentes
    treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
    // Lee el contenido completo del archivo
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(dataFilePath);
    // Recorre las líneas
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        // Separa el contenido de la línea por el caracter *
        var parts = line.Split('*');
        if (parts.Length == 2)
        {
            // Si no está creado el nodo con la primera parte lo añade
            if (!treeView1.Nodes.ContainsKey(parts[0]))
            {
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(parts[0], parts[0]);
            }
            // Seleccionamos el nodo padre con la primera parte
            var firstLevel = treeView1.Nodes[parts[0]];
            // Si no existe un nodo con la segunda parte, lo crea
            if (!firstLevel.Nodes.ContainsKey(parts[1]))
            {
                firstLevel.Nodes.Add(parts[1], parts[1]);
            }
        }
    }
```